# `tabitem` Content Of Conditional `menuitem` Is Showing Only Once in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want a navigation `menuItem` in my `shinydashboard` to be conditional and shown depending on a condition evaluated in `server.R`.

To this end, I have a `conditionalPanel` containing a `menuItem` defined beside a regular `sidebarMenu` in `ui.R` (I use `shinymanager` to authenticate users):

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width=280,
  sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
              menuItem(...),
              menuItem(...,
                       menuSubItem(...),
                       menuSubItem(...)
                       )
              ),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "output.x === 1",
                   menuItem("title", tabName="tabname")
                   )
  )

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "id",
            fluidPage(
              titlePanel("Hello World")
    )),
    tabItem(tabName="tabname",
            titlePanel("mytitle"),
            fluidPage(
              dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
              )
    )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Hello App", titleWidth=280),
  sidebar,
  body
)

ui <- secure_app(ui)
```

In `server.R`, I switch `output.x` depending on the logon details of the logged user:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # login logic: call the server part, check_credentials returns a function to
  # authenticate users
  res_auth = secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials
  )

  # Define the logon details with a reactive variable
  auth_output <- reactive({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
  })

  output$x = reactive({
    auth_output()$role
  })

  # Generate a data table from the DB to show conditionally
  conn = ...
  data = load_data(conn, ...)
  disconnect(conn)

  output$table = dt_render({data})

  # All output variables that need to be transferred to the UI should have
  # suspendWhenHidden = FALSE:
  outputOptions(output, "x", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

The problem: the conditional table is shown only once, whenever I want. After this one time, once I navigate away from it, clicking on the conditional `menuItem` shows no content. The `menuItem` still appears, which means that `output.x === 1` is evaluated properly, but its contents, i.e. the subsequent `tabItem`, remains hidden.

I have tried `isolate` to assign `output.x`, and even fixed it at 1 to no avail. Any leads?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `conditionalPanel` cannot be put inside the default `sidebarMenu`, it must be in its stand-alone conditional `sidebarMenu`, so I must define two `sidebarMenu`s under `dashboardSidebar` in this case. The following modification solves the problem:

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width=280,
  sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
              menuItem(...),
              menuItem(...,
                       menuSubItem(...),
                       menuSubItem(...)
                       )
              ),
  sidebarMenu(id = "conditional_sidebarmenu",
      conditionalPanel(condition = "output.x === 1",
                       menuItem("title", tabName="tabname")
                      )
  )
```